# Raspberry pi won't connect to hidden network

Tags: linux, networking

I have a raspberry pi 4 running raspberry pi os lite(headless). I have a wifi dongle attached to the pi for a better wifi signal (wlan1) as the built-in one was giving me issues, but I couldn't get wlan0 to connect to the network either. I'm using wpa_supplicant which worked perfect at my house but the location I'm at now has a hidden ssid and that seems to be the issue.

Ive tried using scan_ssid=1 which I thought would be the solution but it just didn't connect witch I thought to be very odd. I've tried adding a bunch of other options to get it to work such as 'proto', 'key_mgmt', 'pairwise' etc.

If I use sudo raspi-config to change the wifi network I get the error 'Could not communicate with wpa_supplicant' and 'There was an error running option N2 Wireless LAN'

here is the network configuration in /etc/wpa_supplicant...

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
ssid="Hidden_Network"
scan_ssid=1
psk="password"
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

output of 'ipa && ipr'

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:bd:b8:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.100/8 brd 10.255.255.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::fb4:fdb9:f917:c380/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:e8:ed:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlan1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:16:f9:1a:1e:2e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10.0.0.0/8 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.0.100 metric 202
```

added lines to /etc/dhcpcd.conf...

```
interface eth0
metric 202
static ip_address=10.0.0.100

denyinterfaces wlan0

interface wlan1
metric 302
static ip_address=172.16.0.62
static domain_name_servers=1.1.1.1
static routers=172.16.0.1
```

Comment: Have you been able to connect any other device (phone, laptop, etc) to the WiFi in your new location?

Comment: I guess wlan1 is the problem but you have provided absolutely no details of OS or diagnostics

Comment: @Milliways wlan1 is not the problem I have had it connect to my home network no problem. I also connected wlan0 to my home wifi no problem. also I don't know what details of os or diagnostics to attach

Comment: @Seamus Yes my laptop is connected to the network and my phone as well, only issue us with the pi

Comment: @Milliways I will provide any logs as soon as I know what to provide

Comment: Don't worry about logs (which are rarely helpful). What we do need is details of OS, what is ACTUALLY connected and description of your config files. `ip a && ip r` is a help in diagnosing problems. It is always a problem to rely on default interface enumeration as there is no guarantee which will be `wlan0`

Comment: @Milliways I edited the post and added the output. forgive me I'm new to this site so not sure if there is another way to post that output

Comment: also added the lines of my dhcpcd which worked fine on my home network but thought they could help

Comment: You have committed one of the errors of many new Pi users. Static routes create more problems than they solve and you have got the settings wrong! See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697). The `wlan` does not seem to be connected `sudo iwlist wlan1 scan` will show what it can see. It is unclear what network you are testing (home or otherwise), why you have disabled `wlan0` or why you are trying to use 2 different network segments. **NOTE** do not post Comments, edit your Question with details.

Comment: I will give that a shot, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Both wlan interfaces are DOWN. There is no connection problem with wpa_supplicant, it is an initialization problem of your interfaces. Because we can't see details about your installation I would suggest to flash a fresh [Raspberry Pi OS Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/) on a spare SD Card and follow to [Setting up a Raspberry Pi headless](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md) or [Setting up a wireless LAN via the command line](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md). In the latter guide you also find a section to connect to a hidden network.

If you have the RasPi connected with its default settings using interface **wlan0** then you should plug in your USB/WiFi dongle and disable the built-in interface with this option in `/boot/config.txt`:

```
dtoverlay=disable-wifi
```

provided you are using a RasPi version of 3B, 3B+, 3A+, 4B and Zero W. The dongle will then become **wlan0**. May be it works out of the box. Otherwise you would have to look first for the correct driver to the USB/WiFi dongle.

If you got it to run then you know how to configure your production installation.

Comment: The devices initialize that is not the issue. I will add the dtoverlay, also thank you for the links. Hopefully I will have an answer for this soon